# Can the HOMFLY polynomial be obtained from the Kauffman Polynomial for torus knots?

Tags: knot-theory

This is essentially a yes/no/reference request question.

Let me first just ask my question: Is there a known relationship between the HOMFLY and Kauffman polynomials of torus knots? In particular, is there a published result which says that given the Kauffman polynomial of a torus knot, I can compute its HOMFLY polynomial? If so, any reference would be appreciated.

Here is is some more info:

In the paper http://arxiv.org/abs/q-alg/9507031 of Labastida and Perez, the authors claim that the HOMFLY polynomial of a torus knot can be obtained from the Kauffman Polynomial of the knot. (For the curious: The authors compute a formula for the Kauffman Polynomial of the (m,n) Torus knot which has a shape very similar to a formula for the HOMFLY polynomial discovered (I believe) by Jones. They then note how the HOMFLY formula can be obtained from their Kauffman formula. This relationship is on p. 35 of the paper linked above.)

My concern is that the derivation of formula for the Kauffman polynomial is physics and not mathematics. If anyone is familiar with the above paper and wants to tell me that it is math, I would be happy to hear it. I am *not* asking anyone to do my work for me and read the paper.

Comment: The paper references Chern-Simons theory which is a kind of topological quantum field theory which to me is more mathematics than physics; I am currently working on understanding the said topic so I may write down what I understand which may be helpful to you.